# Keep static variables for a longer time period - Android

Tags: android, memory, static

I am using static variable in a class in Android:

```
class Test{
    static int x;
}
```

This variable is deleted when the class is unloaded or when the VM stops.

I need to keep this variable for a longer time period, but I can't use SharedPreferences or any permanent storage because the information in this static field is sensitive and should not be stored in any accessible storage.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

As the Android service is run in background and is less to be stopped by the OS, I decided to set the static field inside a Service class, but strangely this does not solve the issue, it seems OS will unload the Service class even if the service itself is still running in background, or at least it seems it is loading it again when some event is called, I do not know exactly what is going on but the static field becomes NULL after a period of time as I set a notification in a timer to check for that. anyone can confirm this?

Comment: Use database? You can encrypt it too.

Comment: What do you mean by "accessible storage"? The only people who can access `SharedPreferences` are those who root their device. It is not like your field is somehow magically secure against all comers. After all, with the appropriate tools, people can get at that too. What is the profile of the attacker that you are worried might access this "sensitive" value?

Comment: I know that the SharedPreferences need root access to be read, but it is more hard for attackers to access the RAM, so if I can create a ram disk or something like this it will solve my issue

Comment: A system RAM disk would be as accessible as a physical disk; it just happens to go away when the device reboots. You could create a small Service and query it when your app starts; that would provide a bit more security through obscurity.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html notice the difference in started service one that keeps going till shut down and bound service one that goes till all bindings finish

Comment: Are you looking for application scoped variables that last from one activity to the next till the application is killed?

Comment: No actually I am using this value in a background service

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store sensitive information(key or token) you can use keystore provider , please find the android developer link - http://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html . but it is available from android 4.3 onwards .

Comment: Thank you for your information I will have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

You could create a started service that hangs around after the activity is destroyed. The service can be destroyed when no longer needed. You still need to follow good practices, private variables public getters and setters and be careful in the manifest etc. Static in this case means you only have one copy of the value of the variable regardless of the number of objects of the test class type.

Comment: This is a good solution, and I am trying to follow it, but can you confirm that the Service object is never destroyed?, I did a small test and no guarantee that the Java object of the Service will be saved in the memory, the only thing that is confirmed that the service itself as an application component is not stopped and maintained by Android system